# jQuery Masonry positioning

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to get jQuery Masonry to add consistent spacing on the left and right of masonry container its on. If you look at how [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/) works it keeps consistent spacing on right and left of the browser as you re-size window.

With jQuery Masonry out of the box solution it keeps everything pined to the left but leaves a gap the size of the right side element on the right until it re-sizes enough to push everything to the next row.

Is there anyway to control this using jQuery Masonry?

Anyone out there that can answer this?

Comment: #container: 900px; margin:0 auto;

Comment: Yes but the container should not be fixed width. if its set to 900px then it will not show anything after 900px which is not what pinterest is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like [in this online sandbox](http://www.hopfnordin.se/demo.html) which always centers the container and items within.

Comment: Thanks for this but this is not what Pinterest is doing. They are using margin:0 auto on the wrapper but they are dynamically setting the width but not sure how. In firebug you can see the size changing once the layout changes.

Comment: In the sandbox example, the width dynamically changes depending on the browser window width, just like at Pinterest, so it's centering. Thought that was what you were after, never mind.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I needed to read more clearly the docs.

```
isFitWidth: true
```

This fixes it.